# User creation script avoid duplicate username

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to do an Active Directory search using PowerShell to discover if the username I want to create is already in use,. If it is already in use I want the script to add the following number at the and of the user name.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
    $family= Mclaren
    $first= Tony
    #This part of the script will use the first 5 letters of $family and the first 2 letters of $first and join them together to give the $username of 7 letters
    $username = $family.Substring(0, [math]::Min(5, $family.Length)) + $first.Substring(0, [math]::Min(2, $first.Length))
```

- The user name will look like "**mclarto**" base on that *(username
  take the 5 first letters of the family name plus 2 charof the firstname)*
  a seach is done in AD.
- If there is no result, "mclarto" will be taken as $username **without**
  any number at the end.
- If the search find other users with the same username, the
  username should take the following number, in this case it would be
  **"mclarto1"**.
- If **"mclarto1"** already exist then **"mclarto2"** should be use and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will get you close, it uses the [ActiveDirectory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378937%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) module.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$family = "Mclaren*"

# Get users matching the search criteria
$MatchingUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -like $family' 

if ($MatchingUsers)
{
    # Get an array of usernames by splitting on the @ symbol
    $MatchingUsers = $MatchingUsers | Select -expandProperty UserPrincipalName | %{($_ -split "@")[0]}

    # loop around each user extracting just the numeric part
    $userNumbers = @()
    $MatchingUsers | % { 
        if ($_ -match '\d+')
        {
            $userNumbers += $matches[0]
        }
    }

    # Find the maximum number
    $maxUserNumber = ($userNumbers | Measure-Object -max).Maximum

    # Store the result adding one along the way (probably worth double checking it doesn't exist)
    $suggestedUserName = $family$($maxUserNumber+1)
}
else
{
    # no matches so just use the name
    $suggestedUserName = $family
}

# Display the results
Write-Host $suggestedUserName
```

Comment: Hi David, I can't get through the AD search using a $var: $MatchingUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter 'UserPrincipalName -like "$($family)*"'  Always returning a empty search. If i use the correct SamAccountName instead of the $var I get through it. Is this possible to use Quest AD instead ? or an other way?

Comment: I ran through a problem, If the SamAccountName is already existing the script work well, but if it's a unique name the scrip alway returning a value of Mclaren1 instead of returning the Mclaren value due to it's unique result. I hope my explanation are clear. You think you can help to figure out ?

Comment: I have updated the example by removing double quotes and putting the * in the variable, see if that helps?

Comment: David i've comment your script with the way I solve the AD query part. Also I've edited my question with more details on how username should be handle if you can take a look it would be appreciated

Comment: If I understand the missing requirement, it was missing an an example of how to handle no matches, so I have added that.